# How to save a swift struct to file

Tags: ios, swift, serialization, struct

I want to use structs for the (very simple) model of my app.

However `NSKeyedArchiver` only accepts objects (extending `NSObjects`).

Is there any good way to save a struct to a file?

Comment: Whats the problem? Why not a class?

Comment: Have you tried anything other than `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: I have switched to classes, but I'm thinking of redoing my model as I have to write more sync code. With a lot of asynchronous code going around, pass by reference seems like it could cause some bugs.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple approach I used sometimes. The quantity of code you need to write is no more then in the class/NSCoding scenario.

First of all import the great [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) lib.

### Let's start with a simple struct

```
struct Starship {
    let name: String
    let warpSpeed: Bool
    let captain: String?

    init(name: String, warpSpeed: Bool, captain: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.warpSpeed = warpSpeed
        self.captain = captain
    }
}
```

### Let's make it convertible to/from a JSON

```
struct Starship {
    let name: String
    let warpSpeed: Bool
    let captain: String?

    init(name: String, warpSpeed: Bool, captain: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.warpSpeed = warpSpeed
        self.captain = captain
    }

    init?(json: JSON) {
        guard let
            name = json["name"].string,
            warpSpeed = json["warpSpeed"].bool
        else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.warpSpeed = warpSpeed
        self.captain = json["captain"].string
    }

    var asJSON: JSON {
        var json: JSON = [:]
        json["name"].string = name
        json["warpSpeed"].bool = warpSpeed
        json["captain"].string = captain
        return json
    }
}
```

### That's it. Let's use it

```
let enterprise = Starship(name: "Enteriprise D", warpSpeed: true, captain: "JeanLuc Picard")

let json = enterprise.asJSON
let data = try! json.rawData()

// save data to file and reload it

let newJson = JSON(data: data)
let ship = Starship(json: newJson)
ship?.name // "Enterprise D"
```

Comment: I have declare global `var` like this: `var cartItems = [CartItems]()` but when I use this: `let json = cartItems.asJSON` it is displaying error: `Value of type '[CartItems]' has no member 'asJSON'`. I had added `var asJSON` & `init?(json: JSON)` in my struct.

Comment: @BhavinRamani `cartItems` is an Array so it doesn't have the `asJSON` property.

Comment: I can't change it. So, what should I do? I want to save `cartItems`.

Comment: @BhavinRamani: I can't easily answer you with a comment. You should post your own question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution for Swift 5+

- No need to import anything
- Make your struct codable

```swift
struct Starship: Codable { // Add this
    let name: String
    let warpSpeed: Bool
    let captain: String?

    init(name: String, warpSpeed: Bool, captain: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.warpSpeed = warpSpeed
        self.captain = captain
    }
}
```

- Functions to read from and write to file

```swift
var data: Starship

func readFromFile(filePathURL: URL) throws {
    let readData = try Data(contentsOf: filePathURL)
    self.data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Starship.self, from: readData)
}

func writeToFile(filePathURL: URL) throws {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.data)
    try jsonData.write(to: filePathURL)
}
```