# Should I use NSUserDefault or CoreData for saving the last ten scores?

Tags: swift, core-data, struct, nsuserdefaults

Right now I have a `struct` with multiple dictionaries and string that holds the user's score for each level and the user's name that they type. I then save the `struct` scores into an `NSUserdefault`.

```
struct Scores: Codable {
    var userName: String = ""
    var totalScore: Int = 0
    var highScore: [String : Int] = [:]
    var scoreA: [String : Int]  = [:]
    var scoreB: [String : Int] = [:]
}

UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(scores), forKey:"scores_1")
```

This works well but I will need to save the user's last ten scores. I am wondering if I should use `core-data` or keep using `NSUserdefaults`? Not sure which is best practice.

Edit: Should I save the data in a .json file?

Comment: So basically we are talking about an array of 10 dictinarios, well personally I'd definitely choose UserDefaults...

Comment: Neither. It is not a user preference; it is the app’s data. But CoreData is way overkill. Just write it to a file.

Comment: @matt You mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756121/how-to-save-a-swift-struct-to-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserDefaults is best used to store small amounts of data, and not arrays.

Every time you call the key, the *entire* plist file that it's stored in is called into memory.

eg)

```
let volumeLevel = UserDefaults.Standard.integer(forKey: "volume")
```

So if you are storing an array that grows every time the user plays, eventually you will have memory problems.

With the example you have above, using UserDefaults to store High Score and UserName is fine, but I would recommend using CoreData (or something else) to store an array that has data for each run of the game.